# Angular Material form field control is null

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm trying to implement a MaterialDialog using [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rnqrkqaapqy?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html) and for some reason I get:

```
Cannot read property 'data' of null at new ACDialogComponent
```

My Component

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'acdialog',
    templateUrl: './acdialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./acdialog.component.css']
})
export class ACDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;
    data: string="";
    datatype:string;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ACDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) d) {

        this.data = d.data;
        this.datatype = data.datatype;

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.form = this.fb.group({
            description: ["descriptionhere", []],
        });

    }

    save() {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add new contact</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Data:" formControlName="data">
    </mat-form-field>
    <h4>data type</h4>

    <mat-form-field>
        <select matNativeControl required formControlName="datatype">
            <option value="email">email</option>
            <option value="phone">phone</option>
        </select>
    </mat-form-field>

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button>
    <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

the outer component (the one that opens the dialog)

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    this.dialog.open(ACDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ACDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
        data => console.log("Dialog output:", data)
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you actually pass something as `data`-property of the `config` object when opening the dialog with the `open` function?

Comment: Please see revised answer.

Comment: `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` is not being injected. Do you need this in your component ?

Comment: @sloth I didnt think I needed to since my form was hardcoded. Im only trying to read user input

Comment: @SunilSingh What do you mean MAT_DIALOG_DATA is not being injected?

Comment: What does "my form was hardcoded" mean? How do you open the dialog? That's the interesting question.

Comment: @sloth, I added the outer component. the User presses a button in the outer component then the openDialog() function is fired

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the `data` property of `dialogConfig`, hence `d` is undefined in the constructor of your dialog component.

It seems like it should be an object that has a `data` and a `datatype` property, something like this:

```
...
dialogConfig.data = { data: 'foo', datatype: 'bar' };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be creating your controls for your form, you will need to do something like below to create the controls `data` and `datatype`

```
   import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from "@angular/forms"; 

   ngOnInit() {

        this.form = this.fb.group({
            description: ["descriptionhere", []],
            data: new FormControl(this.data),
            datatype: new FormControl(this.datatype)
        });

    }
```

stackblitz example minus mat-dialog, if applying this to your project does not resolve the issue then there may infact be a problem with the incoming data DI'd into the dialog via data variable as well.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuy1jy?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.ts

**Revision** You also don't appear to be passing your data into the dialog, please try the following.

```
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ACDialogComponent, {
   disableClose: true,
   autoFocus: true,
   data: passYourDataHere 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this to my code, but am still having the same issue

Comment: I had some typo's in my original response, case issues. Do you have latest copy datatype or dataType?

Comment: stackBlitz example for formControl minus the dialog, link attached to answer.

Comment: Please see revision

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot read property 'data' of null at new ACDialogComponent`. Is because a misspelling inside `constructor` body. The variable `data` has never

Look at
`@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) d`

`this.datatype = data.datatype;`

change

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ACDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) d) {

    this.data = d.data;
    this.datatype = data.datatype;

}
```

to

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ACDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) d) {

    this.data = d.data;
    this.datatype = d.datatype;

}
```